# Why isn't Google login working for my React Native Firebase Android app?

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin

i have google login in react app for android and ios after i done with all feature in app its time for deployment first i test login in debug mode it work in iphone and android after that i test release apk android app i test it with android phone i tested login and it work after that i push aab file on internal test and google login work after that i deploy ios version to app store and tested google login and its work after that i push aab file for deploy my android app to playstore but did not work
i am using firebase i create android app and i add sha-1 of my debug file and key store file and internal test sha-1 and App signing key certificate but still google login not work why

google login on android

Comment: the problem was solved the reason was because on 7 May i use "Upgrade your app signing key" for update my App signing key certificate so after added old App signing key certificate to firebase the problem solved

Answer (score 4):

It is cause you haven't added SHA-1 of playstore into Firebase.
Go to Play Console > [Your App] > Setup > App Integrity . Copy SHA-1 from App signing tab and add it to firebase project. You should have the google login working on the same release within 5-10 minutes.

Comment: here i this screenshot you can see i added 4 sha-1 on my firebase project
* debug keystore file
* my upload keystore file
* internal test google console
* App signing key certificate

after that i upload google services json file 

but still same problem it work on ios debug or production it work on internal test when i added aab release file on console
it work with apk release app
the only case when its does't work is live app on google play even if am added sha-1 of App signing key certificate

Comment: the problem was solved the reason was because on 7 May i use "Upgrade your app signing key" for update my App signing key certificate so after added old App signing key certificate to firebase the problem solved –

Comment: I had mistakenly added the "upload" SHA-1 key, not the signing key.  ty